# Confusing syntax

Tags: grammar

SENTENCE: These capilliaries of power can be so innocuous, even commonsensical, as to be undetectable.

I think what confuses me most is the "as to be" part of the sentence and I'm not sure when to use it because I don't fully understand how to use it. I think what this sentence is saying is: power is such an intuitive, low-key part of society that people don't notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [dictionary defintion](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+to+be) of the idiom is "Similar enough to something as to become it." It is generally used in a pattern "X is *so* Y *as to be* Z"

It can often be replaced with "... that it is ...", in your example (slightly edited):

> These capillaries of power are so innocuous that they are undetectable.

Capillaries are the smallest blood veins, and capillaries of power is a metaphor, power is imagined to be flowing into every part of society the way that blood flow from the heart to the smallest muscle. Innocuous means "having no harmful effect". So I think your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Something can be so X as to {VERB} + {COMPLEMENT}

Here are some example uses:

> Tea can be so hot as to be undrinkable.
>
> Siblings can look so much alike as to be mistaken for each other.

**so** + {QUALITY}  means "possessing {quality} to such a degree".  The pattern is often complemented by a clause that expresses the result or implications of having the said quality to such a degree.    **as to** + VERB is just one of the ways of complementing it.

> The days were so torrid as to present a real risk of heat-stroke.
>
> The days were so hot, (that) we could never play tennis after breakfast-time.
>
> He was so skilled as to have every expectation of being a first-round NBA draft-pick.
>
> He was so quick and deadly with the jab as to be a definite contender for the middleweight boxing title.
>
> The train was so unpredictable as to be a totally useless and unreliable way to get to work on time.